# Finding angle $x$, a geometry question

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction, geometric-transformation

Here is the question. Find the value of $x$. [image]
I have solved this question by my own (with 3 different methods). However, all methods of mine are based on the construction of equilateral triangles.I am wondering whether there exist any other possible geometric construction because I don’t think equilateral triangle is the only way out but I couldn’t find any other possible construction apart from equilateral. I would like to understand more about the hidden geometric relation about all given informations so any helps are kindly appreciated.

The answer for $x$ is $30^o$

Comment: You should include your solutions. These may help people to see important relations without spending valuable time duplicating your effort.

Comment: @Blue I just want to have any solution without equilateral triangle. I don’t know if posting solution is a good idea because it may ruin one’s creativity to construct a incredible relations

Comment: This looks like a question about "adventitious angles", and a search will find you earlier questions like it.

Comment: Ruining creativity is not a concern here; this is not a puzzle site. You're asking people for help. Withholding information that could make it easier for those people to render that help is inconsiderate. It's possible that one of your equilateral triangle approaches can be made to avoid equliateral triangles with a minor tweak, which could save someone a great deal of time. ... The least you could do is give the value of $x$ you found; this will save people the trouble of, say, recreating the diagram and measuring it for themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be such that $X,B$ are on the same side of line $AF$ and $AXF$ is equilateral.

Then $F$ is a center of a circle through $A,X,B$ and thus $$\angle XAB = {1\over 2}\angle XFB = 12^{\circ}$$
Now $AX =AF$ and $AK=AB$ so $\triangle AXB\cong \triangle AFK$ (sas) which means $$\angle FKA =  \angle ABX = {1\over 2}\angle ?= 30^{\circ}$$

Comment: Well, i got a strong feeling that a circle can be constructed but I couldn’t form one. Now I see where the circle come. Thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the law of sin:

$$\triangle AFK:\;\;\; {AF \over \sin x} = {AK\over \sin (168-x)}= {AB\over \sin (12+x)} $$

$$\triangle ABC:\;\;\; {AF \over \sin 48} = {AB\over \sin (84)}$$

So $$ \sin x \sin 84 = \sin (12+x)\sin 48$$

So $$\cot x = {\cos 6 -\cos 12 \cos 42\over \sin 12\cos 42}$$

Solving this (calculator) we get $x= 30$.

Comment: I'm curious how did you solve that!

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $AB = AK$ and $AF = FB$.

Let $ABD$ be equilateral. Then $\angle FAD = \angle FAK = 12^{\circ}$. Since $AD =AK$ we have $\triangle FAD\cong \triangle FAK$ (sas) Also notice that $DF\bot AB$ so $$\angle ADF = 30^{\circ}\implies \angle  FKA = 30^{\circ}$$ [image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $BCF$ be equilateral. Then $F$ is a ceneter of circle through $A,B,C$ so $$\angle ABC = {1\over 2}\angle AFC= 12^{\circ}$$
and $$\angle CAB = {1\over 2}\angle BFC= 30^{\circ}$$

Since $AF = BC$ and $AK = AB$ we have $\triangle ABC\cong \triangle AFK$ (sas) and thus $x= 30^{\circ}$.

[image]